# need help understanding how to work with Name Space :(

Tags: javascript, workspace

I was searching over the Internet for good JS practices and found an interesting one (that sadly, I don't understand it entirely)

```
myNameSpace = function(){
  var current = null;
  function init(){...}
  function change(){...}
  function verify(){...}
  return{
    init:init,
    change:change
  }
}();
```

- Where can I use this name space?
- How can I use the names pace?
- Is it really good idea to use this instead of Global?

Source of script: http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/javascript-best-practices/

Comment: I think all those questions are answered in the article.

Comment: Hello Blender, sadly the article assumes that you are already mastered JS, so they don't explain it as I would like

Comment: for *work place* and *work space*, do you mean *namespace*? if so, can you edit your question to use only *namespace*? if not, please explain what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use a code like this, that lets you write OO JavaScript code. You should group only cohesive functions in one unit and build more objects like this as needed.

Note that `function buildFullName` is a private function, since it can't be accessed from outside.

I agree with you that is confusing, without previous JavaScript knowledge. The fact is that a function is a first class Object in JavaScript. You can nest functions within functions, they can have variables, and there are so many ways to combine them, there is no standard way like in Java. I think the article [JavaScript Closure 101](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/closures.shtml) can help you clear things up a bit.

```
/** This is our Object definition and constructor */
function Person(fname, lname) {
    this.firstName = fname;
    this.lastName = lname;
}

/** Anonymous function to avoid polluting the global namespace */
(function () {

    /** This function will be defined public, we prefix the class name */
    function Person_toString() {
        //call buildFullName passing this, we could also call the function
        //as buildFullName(),  and it would work, but wouldn't have 'this'
        return buildFullName.call(this);
    }

    /** Another public function */
    function Person_buildGreeting() {
        return "Hi " + this.firstName;
    }

    /** This function is private! */
    function buildFullName() {
        return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
    }

    /** Here we augment the Object with public functions */
    Person.prototype = {
        toString: Person_toString,
        buildGreeting: Person_buildGreeting
    };

})(); //execute the anonymous function immediately
```

Example usage:

```
var p1 = new Person('Jenny', 'Fairview');
alert("toString()=" + p1.toString());
alert("buildGreeting()=" + p1.buildGreeting());
```

Answer (score 0):

That was one poor article, at least the section on avoiding globals. These things arise when your code gets so incredibly large that eventually you will come to give it a prefix, for example `dojo`. All/Most [dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/)  functions start with `dojo.` so when you load it, it doesn't overwrite your functions (of course this assumes you don't have a function or variable called `dojo`).

If you have 1000 functions in the form

```
function init(){...}
function run(){...}
function start(){...}
```

The argument they're making is that it's easier to do

```
packageName = function{
 function init(){...}
 function run(){...}
 function start(){...}
 return {
  init : init ,
  run : run ,
  start : start
 }
```

than

```
packageName = function{
 init : function init(){...} ,
 run : function run(){...} ,
 start : function start(){...}
}
```

I prefer the latter. It's cleaner, more concise, and less confusing.

Comment: Your preferred syntax is _not_ equivalent to the syntax in the question. The way the question does it the functions can easily call each other directly by name, and (arguably more importantly) `current` and `verify()` are private. Your way can be useful too, but the functions can't call each other without saying `this.functionname()` (which may break depending on how they're called) or by using the `packageName` namespace prefix. (Also, did you mean `packageName` to be assigned to a function or to an object literal?)

Comment: packing 1000 functions together is not a great idea, but I think you wrote just pourparler, not because you mean 1000. If possible a small cohesive unit should be more on the 10 mark.

Answer (score 0):

You can go a little further and use CommonJS or [AMD](http://requirejs.org) modules to construct your application and avoid globals pretty much altogether.  Dojo is moving in this direction, but has not yet migrated away from using dojo.*